# Adding touch pointers in an android app

Tags: android, pointers

I'd like to add more than two pointers.

Here is the current code that works:

```
        if (id == 0)
            textView1.setText(touchStatus);
        else
            textView2.setText(touchStatus);
```

How would I add a third, forth, fifth...?

Answer (score 0):

```
switch(id) {
    case 0:
        textView1.setText(touchStatus);
        break;
    case 1:
        textView2.setText(touchStatus);
        break;
    case 2:
        textView3.setText(touchStatus);
        break;
    case 3:
        textView4.setText(touchStatus);
        break;
    ...
}
```